# Does mremap work with malloc?

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, malloc

Is

```
void * mremap(void *old_address, size_t old_size , size_t new_size, unsigned long flags);
```

compatible with malloc()?

GCC (C++) and using Linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not. Apart from the fact that `malloc` doesn't need to give you an address at a page border (which is what `mremap` expects), it would be dangerous to mess with memory mappings from `malloc` without `malloc` knowing you did it. Use `realloc` instead.

Comment: Additional note: GLIBC's realloc uses `mremap` on Linux when possible.

Answer (score 2):

No, but it's highly likely it would work if your previously malloced memory was page-aligned. Of course malloc-related calls will get cranky later when they discover you've moved their data. Results could include heap invalidation, data corruption, and segmentation faults.

Comment: No, actually with common implementations, the probability of `mremap` working correctly (not horribly corrupting malloc state) when the memory is page-aligned is **zero**. The only way `malloc` will ever return page-aligned memory is if it's **not** using `mmap` as the underlying mechanism, i.e. just using `brk`. That's because a few bytes of bookkeeping information are necessary just before the block returned by malloc, offsetting the page-aligned address obtained by `mmap`.

Comment: Of course it will probably always be okay if you just `mremap` a subrange of the range actually allocated to you by `malloc` as long as you either (1) never free it, or (2) `mmap` new anonymous pages in place of the pages you moved.